# w32time The specific module could not be found

Tags: windows-10, services

My Windows 10 time is ALWAYS wrong. I've tried:

- enabling synchronization settings from: Control Panel-> Date & Time -> Internet Time -> Change Settings -> `time.windows.com` or `time.nist.gov`. With error message:

> An error occurred getting the status of the last synchronization. The RPC serves is unavailable.

- System file checker tool (`sfc /scannow`). With result no problem found.
- Starting *Windows Time* from Windows Services. With error message:

> `System error 126 has occurred.`
>
> `The specified module could not be found.`

- Reregistering `w32tm`. With SAME error message:

> C:>w32tm /debug /disable
>
> C:>w32tm /unregister
>
> W32Time successfully unregistered.
>
> C:>w32tm /register
>
> W32Time successfully registered.
>
> C:>net start w32time
>
> The Windows Time service is starting.
>
> The Windows Time service could not be started.
>
> A system error has occurred.
>
> System error 126 has occurred.
>
> The specified module could not be found.

### How to proceed from now on?

Answer (score 1):

You might check your registry.

1. Navigate to the following Registry key: 
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Parameters`
2. Double click on the `TYPE` key and remove the extra space after the value. 
    *Extra spaces entered after the Value are shown as a blue selected text.*
3. Restart the computer.

REF: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/959113

Comment: Full confession:I'm having and investigating a similar issue and Microsoft's recommendation did nothing for me.